# what would the time complexity of this method be?

Tags: java, big-o

What is the time complexity of the following code?

```
void method1(int n){
  for (int i = 0; i <arr.size()/2; i++){
     System.out.println("");
    }
  }
```

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: Interesting that `n` is unused, and `arr` is not defined.

Comment: let's assume arr is just an array of strings

Comment: I was thinking it would be o( log(n))?

Answer (score 1):

Because the number of iterations is proportional to the size of the array, this would be O(n). In general, you'll ignore any constant multiplications on the number of iterations in determining complexity.

You might find this useful: https://justin.abrah.ms/computer-science/how-to-calculate-big-o.html

I'm also guessing that this is a homework problem, so I would encourage you to contact your instructor or TA for additional help. Any good instructor is happy to spend whatever time is necessary to make sure that their students understand the material.

Comment: Note that the "n" in `O(n)` would mean `arr.size()`, and not the `int n` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity of this code depends on the number of time the loop will execute

let's assume the length of `arr` is `m` then the loop is going to execute `m / 2`

But the complexity is not `O(m / 2)` instead it is `O(m)` because we drop off constants when finding the complexity.